# Specifying initial value of `x` in `for(x in object)` loops

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

If I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var mycars = new Array();
            mycars[0] = "Saab";
            mycars[1] = "Volvo";
            mycars[2] = "BMW";

            var x = 1;

            document.write("Value of x: " + x + "<br /><br />");

            for (x in mycars)
            {
                document.write(x + ": " + mycars[x] + "<br />");
            }

            document.write("<br />Value of x: " + x + "<br />");
            document.write("Number of cars: " + mycars.length);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the output:

```
Value of x: 1

0: Saab
1: Volvo
2: BMW

Value of x: 2
Number of cars: 3
```

Without changing the for-in loop to a for loop, is there any way to make it so the first element ("Saab") is not displayed? I would like the output to be:

```
Value of x: 1

1: Volvo
2: BMW

Value of x: 2
Number of cars: 3
```

Comment: you can add a if condition ..

Comment: check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use for..in loops to go through arrays anyway.  From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> "Also, because order of iteration is
>   arbitrary, iterating over an array may
>   not visit elements in numeric order."

So not only can you not skip the "first" element, you can't even rely on the first one being consistent!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `for..in` loops to loop through arrays.  Use `for..in` only for looping through objects.  Doing otherwise can have unintended consequences, that can seem baffling.

Use a standard `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++)
{
    document.write(i + ": " + mycars[i] + "<br />");
}
```

If you want to miss the first item out, set `i` to `1` initially, rather than `0`.  You should probably put a comment in, so you know what's happening if you ever come back to this bit of code.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just stick to the C++ way of doing it. :)

Answer (score -1):

To achieve exactly what you want, have such code:

```
var x = 1;
document.write("Value of x: " + x + "<br /><br />");
while (x < mycars.length) {
{
    document.write(x + ": " + mycars[x] + "<br />");
    x++;
}
x--;

document.write("<br />Value of x: " + x + "<br />");
document.write("Number of cars: " + mycars.length);
```